# Call my own Java code from C#

Tags: c#, java, c++, string, java-native-interface

Having my own Java code I'm using C# to call some unmanaged code that call (via JNI) the java code. I'm using JNI since I need to ensure:

- the ability that the Java code will run over real JVM and not over some .NET VM
- the ability to attach to the VM for debugging (IKVM does'nt support it)
- I need free solution
- The current free solutions are not applicable (e.g. IKVM)

Anyway, my question is how can I manage strings passed between these layers in the best manner without leaks.
I'm doing something like:

```
[DllImport(@"MyDll.dll")]
public extern static void receive_message(string receDest, StringBuilder response);
```

This means I'm allocating the memory for the response in the managed code.
I want to avoid that since I don't know in advance the response length. How can I write a JNI appropriate method that will allocate the right buffer for the managed code without leaks. The JNI code should be thread safe.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Guy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *may* need JNI, but your requirements don't really indicate it.

The requirement to *use a real JVM* does not dictate the use of JNI.  I'd suggest sharpening your requirements, or considering looser coupling.  For example, socket comms, web services, a shared database, a shared file, or [a queue](http://MsmqJava.codeplex.com).

If you really need Java and .NET to be run in the same process, with tight coupling, consider [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/).
They've solved the problem you are confronting.

Comment: 1. JNBridge is not free.
2. I didn't understand how can I configure the JVM.
3. In their samples you need to load the JVM by your own (calling the java directly)
Thanks,
Guy

Comment: I understand JNI is not free.  Didn't see that as a requirement. How much is your time worth?

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to keep it simple by using sockets to communicate between the two processes.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in trying to convert your Java bytecode code in .NET CIL with [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/).

Comment: This is not an option since:
1. I need the java code to be in java and I need to debug it.
2. I don't want to run over VM other than "real" JVM (not IKVM)
Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to make a remote call into the java program from your .NET-code.

With your current skillset I would suggest that you create a web service in the Java machine - this is relatively easy in Java 6 - and based on the WSDL create a client in your .NET program.

This is probably the cleanest solution with todays technologies.

If that for some reason isn't good enough, then add to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Guy --  Regarding Cheeso's response, and your respones to it:

- JNBridgePro does allow the JVM to be started automatically and run inside the .NET process (in addition to the option of starting it explicitly).  See the "shared-memory" communications mechanism discussed in the documentation.
- JNBridgePro does allow you to attach a Java debugger, even when the JVM is running inside the .NET process.  Contact support@jnbridge.com for details, as well as for details on configuring the JVM.
- Can't do much about it not being free, but it might be worth your while to check it out anyway.

Disclosure: Yes, I am with JNBridge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/) as a bridge library. Or you could just look at source code and grab some ideas (LGPL/GPL).