# Calling java code from c#

Tags: java, c#, .net, jar

I want to call the following Java object and method from C# code. Is there any way to do it?

```
// Create a new validator using validation artifacts from Difi.
Validator validator = ValidatorBuilder.newValidator().build();

// Validate business document.
Validation validation = validator.validate(Paths.get("/path/to/document.xml"));

// Print result of validation.
System.out.println(validation.getReport().getFlag());
```

The code is from 
https://github.com/difi/vefa-validator

Comment: did you perform a basic internet search? Clearly not : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129989/how-to-call-java-code-from-c ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063037/call-my-own-java-code-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use java code with c#
2. You can just use a java - c# converter.